# How do I change the year interval on a Pandas DataFrame area plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dts


def use_matplot():

    ax = df.plot(x='year', kind="area" )

    years = dts.YearLocator(20)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)

    fig = ax.get_figure()
    fig.savefig('output.pdf')


dates = np.arange(1990,2061, 1)
dates = dates.astype('str').astype('datetime64')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, dates.size, size=(dates.size,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df['year'] = dates

cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
df = df[cols]

use_matplot()
```

In the above code, I get an error, "ValueError: year 0 is out of range" when trying to set the YearLocator so as to ensure the X-Axis has year labels for every 20th year. By default the plot has the years show up every 10 years. What am I doing wrong? Desired outcome is simply a plot with 1990, 2010, 2030, 2050 on the bottom. (Instead of default 1990, 2000, 2010, etc.)

Comment: Sure, start by providing a [mcve]. I.e. create some dataframe in the code such that the code itself is runnable and reproduces your problem. Once that is done one may easily find a solution.

Comment: Thank you. I will see what I can do today. I guess it will be good practice to create a separate example. In the meantime if you know the method to call for changing an x-axis interval so instead of it reading 2000, 2010, 2020, ... 2060, it reads 2000, 2020, 2040, 2060. I.e. I just want less labels. Then please let me know :)

Comment: I've updated my code to something thats minimal, complete and verifiable. Hope this helps. It still gives me an error though. If I remove the YearLocator then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the years are simple numbers, you may opt for not using them as dates at all and keeping them as numbers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = np.arange(1990,2061, 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,dates.size,size=(dates.size,3)),columns=list('ABC'))
df['year'] = dates

cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
df = df[cols]

ax = df.plot(x='year', kind="area" )
ax.set_xticks(range(2000,2061,20))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Apart from that, using Matplotlib locators and formatters on date axes created via pandas will [most often fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44214830/4124317). This is due to pandas using a completely different datetime convention. In order to have more freedom for setting custom tickers for datetime axes, you may use matplotlib. A stackplot can be plotted with `plt.stackplot`. On such a matplotlib plot, the use of the usual matplotlib tickers is unproblematic.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dts

dates = np.arange(1990,2061, 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,dates.size,size=(dates.size,3)),columns=list('ABC'))
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(dates.astype(str)) 

cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
df = df[cols]

plt.stackplot(df["year"].values, df[list('ABC')].values.T)

years = dts.YearLocator(20)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(years)

plt.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again. Question: why do we need to convert the years column in the dataframe to values in order for the "yearlocator" to work? If it's a datetime method shouldnt it work with datetime xaxis values?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to values"? As the answer says, "pandas is using a completely different datetime convention". So the only problem is that the pandas axis formatter cannot be easily adjusted to show a different interval than the default one.

Comment: So basically, it doesn't matter if the format of x-values are supplied as integers or as datetime64 types when fed into the stackplot method, when using YearLocator.

Comment: No, the first solution uses numbers without a YearLocator,  the second uses dates and a YearLocator. You will only be able to use a Date locator for dates.

Comment: Sorry - I thought the .values argument didn't pass on the datatype (only the integer/float values). But it does! Thanks again.

Comment: The `.values` attribute is the DataFrame without column names or index. This is a numpy array and it has the same datatype as the dataframe columns, because internally DataFrames *are* mre or less extended numpy arrays. (Hence `.values` can indeed be an attribute and not a method that would convert something.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [set_xticklabels](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) to specify values of x axis tick marks:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(sum([[i,''] for i in range(1990, 2060, 20)], []))
# [1990, '', 2010, '', 2030, '', 2050, '']
```

[image: Image Output]