# matplotlib subplots with dates on x axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have a few data_frames like this:

```
>>> roll_av.shape
Out[14]: (274, 2)

>>> roll_av.tail()
Out[12]: 
            week  month
Date              
2017-10-12 0.001 -0.016
2017-10-13 0.231  0.020
2017-10-16 0.180  0.018
2017-10-17 0.235  0.021
2017-10-18 0.187  0.020

>>> roll_av.index
Out[1]: Index([u'2016-08-11', u'2016-08-12', u'2016-08-13', u'2016-08-14', 
u'2017-06-08', ....... u'2017-10-16', u'2017-10-17', u'2017-10-18'],
  dtype='object', name=u'Date')
```

If I do this, I get a plot with x axis as dates:

```
roll_av.plot()
```

[image]

However, if I do the following, the dates disappear.

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
for i in np.arange(4):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(221 + i)
    roll_avg = get_roll_avg(params)
    ax.plot(roll_av)
```

On doing this instead, I get an error:

```
    >>> ax.plot(roll_av.index,roll_av)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\...\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1374, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
  File "C:\...\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1504, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "C:\...\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 1515, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()
  File "C:...\matplotlib\lines.py", line 874, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "C:\...\matplotlib\lines.py", line 575, in recache
    x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)
  File "C:\...\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2017-10-18
```

Is there any simple way to solve this?

Comment: What is `get_roll_avg` doing? Seems to be converting your index to a string.

Comment: edited to show index. should i convert index to datetime?

Comment: @dayum, yes convert `index` to DateTime. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, your index is a string. You can easily convert it to `datetime` before plotting.

```
roll_av.index = pd.to_datetime(roll_av.index)
```

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47017318/5874320) for controlling the date tick value/label formatting (if interested).