# How to align xlabels and ylabels in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am plotting heatmap of features but  the feature names on x and y axes conincide with each other. So how can I align x axis feature names vertically and y axis feature names horizontally so that they do not overlap.

Code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
corr = data.loc[:,'PERID':'PRXRETRY'].corr()

sns.set(font_scale=0.8)
sns.heatmap(corr, 
            xticklabels=corr.columns.values,
            yticklabels=corr.columns.values,cmap="YlGnBu",annot=True)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I guess I forgot to explicitely state *"... under the condition that it hasn't been asked before"* in [my last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315084/how-to-resize-the-correlation-plot-for-better-visualization?noredirect=1#comment85643788_49315084).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
hm = sns.heatmap(corr, cmap="YlGnBu", annot=True)
hm.set_xticklabels(labels=corr.columns.values, rotation=90)
hm.set_yticklabels(labels=corr.columns.values, rotation=0)
```