# Set X-Axis hourly in matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

How is it possible to show just the hours and minutes in the X-Axis like:
00:00 1:00 2:00 ... 8:00

```
von = pd.to_datetime("08.23.17 00:00",infer_datetime_format=True) # Zeitformat: MM.DD.YY HH:MM
bis = pd.to_datetime("08.23.17 08:00",infer_datetime_format=True)

graph = solardaten[['FriWa_VL','FriWa_RL','FriWa_Vpunkt','Speicher_oben']].loc[von:bis]

plt.rcParams.update({'lines.linewidth': 4}) # Increase line width in the plots
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 28})
a=graph.plot(figsize=[15,8])
a.set_ylabel("Temperatur in °C", rotation=90)
ticklab = a.yaxis.get_ticklabels()[0]
trans = ticklab.get_transform()
a.set(xlabel="Zeit", title="keine thermosiphonische Strömung")
a.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.show()
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213781/pandas-dataframe-line-plot-display-date-on-xaxis).

Comment: Thanks, but i cant find a question or answer to "Dates" and "xaxis".

Comment: I linked you to one.

Comment: Ok, it works sometimes...