# How to add x-axis on plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot some data, but I don't know how I can add the date values on the x-axis on my graph.  Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline
%pylab inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 9)
df["msft"].plot(grid = True)
```

[image]

The description of the image is a plot, but the x-axis just has numbers, but I am looking for dates to appear on x-axis.  The dates are in the date column in the dataframe.

Here is what the dataframe looks like:

```
                  date  msft  nok  aapl  ibm  amzn
1  2018-01-01 09:00:00   112    1   143  130  1298
2  2018-01-01 10:00:00   109   10   185  137  1647
3  2018-01-01 11:00:00    98   11   146  105  1331
4  2018-01-01 12:00:00    83    3   214  131  1355
```

Can you offer some help on what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column `date` is just another column for pandas, you have to tell the program that you want to plot against this specific one. One way is to plot against this column:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
#load dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
#convert date column to datetime object, if it is not already one
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

#plot the specified columns vs dates
df.plot(x = "date", y = ["msft", "ibm"], kind = "line", grid = True)
plt.show()
```

For more pandas plot options, please have a look at [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

Another way would be to set `date` as the index of the dataframe. Then you can use your approach:

```
df.set_index("date", inplace = True)
df[["msft", "ibm"]].plot(grid = True) 
plt.show()
```

The automatic date labels might not be, what you want to display. But there are ways to format the output and [you can find examples on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44214830/8881141).

Answer (score -1):

one way to do it is the [`set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) function, though Mr. T's answer is the proper way to go

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
df["msft"].plot(grid = True)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['date'])
plt.xticks(np.arange(4))
```

with the data provided:

[image: set_xticklabels]

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering how I could take the dates from the dataframe and apply them to x-axis.

Comment: In my example, I have the indexes on the x axis.