# Plot with Matplotlib using List - Datetime - Different Behaviour on Format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

**Why Matplotlib has this strange behaviour with Date Data Type?**

> Matplotlib allows you to natively plots python datetime instances, and for the most part does a good job picking tick locations and string formats. 
>   From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html)  "Fixing common date annoyances"

I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213781/pandas-dataframe-line-plot-display-date-on-xaxis/44214830#44214830) that gave me some clues related to [Matplotlib Date Format](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#module-matplotlib.dates).
I also read the most voted questions about `matplotlib` and `Datetime` but I still don't understand the following behaviour.

```
#timestamp is a <class 'list'>
timestamp=['2019-02-04', '2019-01-15', '2018-10-08', '2018-07-09',
           '2018-04-09', '2018-02-08', '2017-09-08', '2017-09-08',
           '2017-07-07', '2017-04-07', '2017-01-09', '2016-10-07',
           '2016-07-01', '2016-03-25', '2015-12-27', '2015-09-25',
           '2015-06-26', '2015-03-27', '2014-12-24', '2014-10-06',
           '2014-07-02', '2014-03-28', '2013-12-20', '2013-09-27',
           '2013-06-11', '2013-03-27', '2012-12-27', '2012-09-26',
           '2012-06-13', '2012-03-28', '2011-12-14', '2011-09-28',
           '2011-06-14', '2011-03-30', '2010-12-15', '2010-09-29',
           '2010-06-19', '2010-03-31', '2009-12-29', '2009-09-30',
           '2009-06-17', '2009-04-01', '2008-12-20', '2008-08-25',
           '2008-08-25', '2008-06-19', '2008-03-19', '2008-03-19',
           '2006-04-11', '2005-12-27', '2005-09-28', '2005-07-02',
           '2005-04-20', '2004-12-21', '2004-10-20', '2004-07-21',
           '2003-09-22', '2003-08-20', '2002-12-31']

#time_python is a <class 'datetime.datetime'>
time_python=[datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d") for d in timestamp]
#time_series is a <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
time_series=pd.to_datetime(timestamp)

array=np.arange(1,len(timestamp)+1) 

time_2_num=mdates.date2num(time_series.to_pydatetime())

#First plot using the List Format as x axes
plt.subplot(411)
plt.bar(timestamp,array)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')

#Second plot using the padas Datatime Format as x axes
plt.subplot(412)
plt.bar(time_series,array)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 1.2)

#Third plot using the DateTime Format as x axes 
plt.subplot(413)
plt.bar(time_python,array)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 1.2)

#Fourth plot using the Matplot Date Format as x axes 
plt.subplot(414)
plt.bar(time_2_num,array)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 1.2)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()  

plt.show()
```

The desired result is obviously the first plot.

[image]

**I want to understand better why the bars of the II,III,IV plot has this representation, different from the I. The y input is the same for the 4 plots.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the difference become more obvious if you remove the line `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()` because that removes the labels from all but the last plot.

[image]

**First Plot**

The first plot is "categorical" plot. The values for the x axis are strings. They are shown one by one in the order they appear in the input list/array and each gets its own label. In this case matplotlib does not know that the strings represent dates and indeed you could also supply a list of fruits instead (`["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", ...]`)

**Second / Third plot**

Those is the intended behaviour for datetime plots in matplotlib. Matplotlib works with `datetime` or `numpy.datetime64` objects equally well. The axis is a true scale in the sense of a line with a defined linear metric (i.e. the distance between monday and wednesday is twice as large as between saturday and sunday). Concerning the units of such datetime axes the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib-date-format) states

> Matplotlib represents dates using floating point numbers specifying the number of days since 0001-01-01 UTC, plus 1.

Because matplotlib recognizes the datetime input, it will automatically choose a date locator and formatter as to have the ticks at useful locations

**Fourth plot**

The fourth plot is in principle identical to the two above. The only difference that matplotlib has no chance of knowing that the numbers (like 731000) are meant to denote dates (they could be distance between earth and satellites as well).

You can still get the same appearance as in the two plots above by manually setting a locator and formatter, e.g. adding the following lines to the last plot

```
loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
```

results in the same plot as the second, third plot

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest now is clearer. But why we have 59 bars plotted in the first plot and only 6 in the other three? How the different X axis influence the total number of bars?

Comment: You almost certainly have 59 bars in the other plots, but they are only 0.8-days wide, and hence don't cover a pixel, and thus don't show up.  Increase the dpi of your figure, or set the width of the bars to something wider, keeping in mind the units are days.

Comment: No, you have the same number of bars. Many of them are just not seen, because the bar width is less than a day by default. So in this concrete case, you have 16 years ~= 5840 days. Those distribute along some 580 pixels. So the probability that a bar is shown is roughly 10%. I would suggest to give the bars an edge, adding `linewidth=1, edgecolor="C0"` to the `bar` command. Alternatively make the bars wider, `width=15`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first graph, you are sending `timestamp` which is purely strings. Matplotlib treats it as strings. If you look at the plot on its own, you will see the labels are just the strings from `timestamp` in the same order.

The other 3 methods convert this string into timestamps, which matplotlib treats differently.

```
timestamp=['2019-02-04', '2019-01-15', '2018-10-08', '2018-07-09',
       '2018-04-09', '2018-02-08', '2017-09-08', '2017-09-08',
       '2017-07-07', '2017-04-07', '2017-01-09', '2016-10-07',
       '2016-07-01', '2016-03-25', '2015-12-27', '2015-09-25',
       '2015-06-26', '2015-03-27', '2014-12-24', '2014-10-06',
       '2014-07-02', '2014-03-28', '2013-12-20', '2013-09-27',
       '2013-06-11', '2013-03-27', '2012-12-27', '2012-09-26',
       '2012-06-13', '2012-03-28', '2011-12-14', '2011-09-28',
       '2011-06-14', '2011-03-30', '2010-12-15', '2010-09-29',
       '2010-06-19', '2010-03-31', '2009-12-29', '2009-09-30',
       '2009-06-17', '2009-04-01', '2008-12-20', '2008-08-25',
       '2008-08-25', '2008-06-19', '2008-03-19', '2008-03-19',
       '2006-04-11', '2005-12-27', '2005-09-28', '2005-07-02',
       '2005-04-20', '2004-12-21', '2004-10-20', '2004-07-21',
       '2003-09-22', '2003-08-20', '2002-12-31']

array=np.arange(1,len(timestamp)+1) 
plt.bar(timestamp,array)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) The first graph is clear to me. I am trying to understand the others with the others Data Type  :)