# matplotlib wrong location of the first tick with timeseries plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization

my matplotlib version is 3.0.0

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mdates as mdates
import pandas as pd

years = range(2016, 2025)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(years), 1, figsize=(10, 20))

for ax, year in zip(axes, years):
    common_idx = pd.date_range(str(year), str(year+1), closed='left')
    s = pd.Series(42, common_idx)
    s.plot(ax=ax)

    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
    ax.set_title(year)

fig.set_tight_layout(True)
```

the above code is mcve. and the below is the result.

[image]

why do graphs in 2016, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2022, 2023 put the first tick on the wrong location?
I can't even find any pattern (like leap year)...

Comment: In general the datetime utilities of pandas and matplotlib are incompatible. If you want to use the datetime locators from `matplotlib.dates` you would need to pass the `x_compat=True` option in pandas plotting methods. See [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213781/pandas-dataframe-line-plot-display-date-on-xaxis).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest First of all, sorry for the late reply and second you saved my day! Finally, really really thank you!